# How can I access a model's data inside a new view file?

Tags: php, database, yii, model

I want to access all the data of a model in one of its views, which I made and called `searching.php`. I wrote an action in the `business` controller which is like this:

```
public function actionSearching()
    {
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
        $this->layout='//layouts/main';
            $this->render('searching');
    }
```

In the view of `business/searching` I want to access all the data of a model (Business). This includes business_name, business_description etc. But when I run this code I get `error 500, Undefined variable: model`.

Here is my searching.php file code:

```
foreach ($model as $ma)
{
    echo $ma->business_name;
}
```

I am a yii bie, I know very little about yii. How can I access all the data in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your models in the `view` when you call `render()`.

In your controller:

```
public function actionSearching() {
    $models = Business::model()->findAll();

    $this->layout='//layouts/main';
    $this->render('searching', array(
        'models'=>$models,
    ));
}
```

In your view:

```
foreach($models as $model) {
    echo $model->business_name;
}
```

Comment: what is base ? getting this error include(Base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, i meant business (or your model class name).

Comment: oh i change base with business, its resplendent :) Yahooo Thanks sir thanks so much :) God Bless you

Comment: Nice! I am glad that I helped you. Please don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted one.