# How can I echo in else that "The searched business does not exist"?

Tags: php, database, yii, view, model

My last question was how to access model's data in one of its view after got successful answer I implemented it. [This was my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680956/how-can-i-access-a-models-data-inside-a-new-view-file/33681095?noredirect=1#comment55135461_33681095)

Now its working good, but how can I echo that when a user search a `business`, which does not exist in the database, the system echo

> Business not exist

I tried to insert `else` in the `foreach` loop, but it echoes "`Business not exist`" many times.

I am posting user searched business name in my `landing.php` which is my layout to `searching` view.

I am pasting my Landing.php, Business controller and the view file which I called `Searching`

My landing.php:

```
<form action="business/searching" method="POST">                     
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <h2 class="title">
            Find the best places to eat, drink, shop, or visit in Islamabad. 
        </h2>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="business" id="lg" placeholder="I'm looking for...."/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sm"  placeholder="Islamabad" disabled=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my Business controller

```
 public function actionSearching()
 {
     $models = Business::model()->findAll();
     $modeladd = Address::model()->findAll();

     $this->layout='//layouts/main';
     $this->render(
         'searching', 
         array(
             'models' => $models,
             'modeladd' => $modeladd,        
         )
     );
 }
```

Searching view Its bit complicated but on ask i can explain.

```
    <div class="gap"> </div>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">

                <ul class="booking-list">
                <li>  
  <?php foreach($models as $model)  //getting business model from searching action in business controller
      {
      $name=$model->business_name; //storing name
       $id=$model->id;   //storing id in order to use this id in address if as addres has no business_name
        if($name== $_POST["business"])    //matching name
                 {  ?>
    <a class="booking-item" href="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $id?>">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
     <img src="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image;?>" alt="Not availble" title="Image business" />
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="booking-item-rating">
    </div>
      <h5 class="booking-item-title"><?php echo $model->business_name; ?></h5>
                <?php   foreach($modeladd as $mo) //getting address model from searching action in business controller
          {
               $addbizid=$mo->business_id;   //businessid from address table
            if($id== $addbizid)     //wanted to match business name, but couldnot as addres has no business name only business_id, so i get business_id
                                     //  from above after the searched business name is matched and now comparing that id with addres->businessid
            {
   $street=$mo->street_number;   //if match store address in these variable and then simple print them below
     $sector=$mo->sector; 
     $city=$mo->city; ?>
                <p class="booking-item-address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php echo $street; echo $sector; ;echo $city;?>  <?php  }} ?></p>
               <p class="booking-item-description"> <?php echo $model->business_description;?>
                </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                      <?php }}  ?>
                </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                  </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="booking-item-dates-change mb30">
        <h3>Not here? Tell us what we're missing.</h3><p>If the business you're looking for isn't here, add it!</p>
        <a href="addbusiness.php" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Business Page</a>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="gap"></div>
        </div>
<div class="gap"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try to format your PHP code. That will increase readability..

Comment: let me do this for you sir

Comment: why are you doing the filtering in php? If you want to display only search results, you don't suck across the entire database and throw away 99% of the records.

Comment: JQuery is perfect for realtime search results. Maybe that's an option? http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/7BUmG/1133/

Comment: when the searched business match with the already exisiting business, it will show me the business name, its id, its address in my search. So i have to suck the entire database to match the business

Comment: I am new to yii so i am pretty much messed up.

Comment: I just want to show that, in foreach loop, the searched business should match with the existing business, if it match show business_name, business_description, address. if not show me "business not exist". Hope i explained it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use endif, end foreach loop if you want to use if else in foreach loop.

```
    <?php

/* 
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/  
//echo $_POST["business"]; echo "</br>";
//foreach($modeladd as $mo)
//  {
//   
//     $street=$mo->street_number;
//    
//     $address=$mo->sector; 
//    
//      $city=$mo->city;
//      $business_id=$mo->business_id;
//      echo $street; echo ("<br />");echo $address;  echo ("<br />");echo $city; echo ("<br />");echo $business_id;
//}

?>
<?php $matchFound = false; ?>
<div class="gap"> </div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<ul class="booking-list">

<li>  
<?php foreach($models as $model): ?>  
  <?php  //removing foreach outerloop
$name=$model->business_name; //storing name
$id=$model->id;   //storing id in order to use this id in address if as addres has no business_name
?>
<?php if($name== $_POST["business"]):    //matching name
  $matchFound = true;            //removing if match
?>

<a class="booking-item" href="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $id?>">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
<img src="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image;?>" alt="Not availble" title="Image business" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="booking-item-rating">
</div>
<h5 class="booking-item-title"><?php echo $model->business_name; ?></h5>
<?php   foreach($modeladd as $mo) //getting address model from searching action in business controller
{
$addbizid=$mo->business_id;   //businessid from address table
if($id== $addbizid)     //wanted to match business name, but couldnot as addres has no business name only business_id, so i get business_id
//  from above after the searched business name is matched and now comparing that id with addres->businessid
{
$street=$mo->street_number;   //if match store address in these variable and then simple print them below
$sector=$mo->sector; 
$city=$mo->city; ?>
<p class="booking-item-address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 
<?php echo $street; echo $sector; ;echo $city;?> 
 <?php 
}
} 
?>
</p>
<p class="booking-item-description"> <?php echo $model->business_description;?>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
break;
 endif;                   //removing if matc outer loop
 endforeach;              //removing for each outer loop
?>
    <?php if (!$matchFound): ?>
    <?php echo "No data found for the room number you entered."; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="booking-item-dates-change mb30">
<h3>Not here? Tell us what we're missing.</h3><p>If the business you're looking for isn't here, add it!</p>
<a href="addbusiness.php" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Business Page</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gap"></div>
</div>
<div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```